# Xcode - generate implementation shortcut

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-studio-2013

I use c++ for creating cross platform games and recently switched from visual studio to xcode.I really like it's features but I was unable to find some of the shortcuts I used on daily basis with VS (with help of visual assist plugin):

In visual studio I could just shift+alt+q and it opened a list with a whole bunch of useful stuff like implement function in cpp file,rename, or encapsulate field. How can I acheive this in Xcode? The most important for me is tu generate implementations based on .h file since all of my files contain only one class and the name is the same and it really speeds up development.

Comment: Even eclipse with c++ plugin can do that (it can even implement all unimplemented functions at one time.I can just simply write h file and the hit shortcut and all of the functions are blank-implemented in cpp file. Why I cant find this feature in xcode :<